# Use Jquery to add a div dynamically based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a div dynamically based on a the text of the parent div.

My html is:

```
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Living Room:</strong> Yes</div>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Kitchen:</strong> No</div>
```

So I want a div to be insert such that if YES, `<div class="fa fa-check"></div>` should be added right before the `<strong>` and if No `<div class="fa fa-cross"></div>` should be added.

Using the jQuery below i have managed to add a class to `<div class="listing_detail col-md-4">` however i cant figure out how to add the div.

jQuery:

```
$('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').closest('.listing_detail').addClass('yes');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akfndk67/)

Comment: Are you generating the HTML code? If yes, you should do it there, when rendering, not on client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').prepend('<div class="fa fa-check"></div>');
```

This would result in:

```
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><div class="fa fa-check"></div><strong>Living Room:</strong> Yes</div>
```

Comment: Oops sorry if i overwritten any of your edit, just that `.closest('.listing_detail')` has no meaning here

Comment: @A.Wolff - no worries, I was just reformatting it so it wasn't all on one line

Answer (score 0):

**[prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** should do the work . **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/akfndk67/1/)**

In the below example, if the `.listing_detail` div contains class yes , it is gonna **prepend** div check as its **first child** i.e in this case it will prepend before strong.

```
 $('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').prepend('<div class="fa fa-check"></div>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the jQuery [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').closest('.listing_detail').addClass('yes').prepend('<div class="fa fa-check"><input type="checkbox"> Check me</div>');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akfndk67/4/)

> **EDIT:** made a mistake with before/after

Comment: realy realy don't understand why my answer was been downvoted even without any argumentation?.. i've spended my time to maybe help and to finaly receive a downvote? Just why?. Thank you.

Comment: Check your own code. You added the div after the strong element and the OP asked for before.

Comment: MMM, ok, agree. Was a language mistake. I'm sorry for the mistake I made, English isnt my native language